# writing div from table in html

Tags: html

need help in writing table into div format for code

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
            <tr>
              <td width="15%" background="images/r.jpg" bgcolor="#026aa1"><p align="center" class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
                <p align="center" class="style4 style5">1% Dying </p>
              <p align="center" class="style4">&nbsp;</p></td>
              <td width="22%" background="images/g.jpg" bgcolor="#75a81a"><p align="center" class="style6">2% Dying </p></td>
              <td width="28%" background="images/o.jpg" bgcolor="#d85700"><p align="center" class="style6">Product Name </p></td>
              <td width="32%" background="images/p.jpg" bgcolor="#94499b"><p align="center" class="style6">Fastness to </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td width="15%" bgcolor="#f9f5f5"><p align="center"><img width="80" height="37" src="feature_shortcodes - Copy_clip_image002.jpg" alt="A27.jpg"> </p></td>
              <td width="22%" bgcolor="#f9f5f5"><p align="center"><img width="80" height="37" src="feature_shortcodes - Copy_clip_image003.jpg" alt="A28.jpg"> </p></td>
              <td width="28%" bgcolor="#f9f5f5"><p align="center"><u>Acid Black    10BX&nbsp;</u> <br>
              CI-Black1 </p></td>
              <td width="32%" bgcolor="#f9f5f5"><p align="center">Lights : 3-4<br>
                Washing : 3-4<br>
              Perspiration : 3-4 </p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="15%" bgcolor="#f1eeee"><p align="center"><img width="80" height="37" src="feature_shortcodes - Copy_clip_image004.jpg" alt="A25.jpg"> </p></td>
              <td width="22%" bgcolor="#f1eeee"><p align="center"><img width="80" height="37" src="feature_shortcodes - Copy_clip_image005.jpg" alt="A26.jpg"> </p></td>
              <td width="28%" bgcolor="#f1eeee"><p align="center"><u>Acid BrownNR&nbsp;</u><br>
              CI-Brown75 </p></td>
              <td width="32%" bgcolor="#f1eeee"><p align="center">Lights : 4<br>
                Washing : 3<br>
              Perspiration : 3-4 </p></td>
            </tr>
```

as table format is not supported for seo .

Comment: If you have table data, use table. Div is a bad idea for these data type. What you meant by _table is not supported for seo_? Forget, it's a nonsense :-)

Comment: @Panther - someone told me that google robots cant crawl table. and table is old version of making website new way is div..

Comment: do check website http://www.hirenenterprises.com/our-product.html to understand what am i talking about.

Comment: Table is normal html tag for table data. Robots index table data correctly. Only one thing which isn't recommended  is make website layout by tables. Nothing else.

Comment: You have table data, use table. It's the only right way how to show these datas.

Comment: @panther - while checking website thru w3c validator i am getting error for following url http://www.hirenenterprises.com/our-product.html and  i am suggested to use css

Comment: Google bot doesn't validate your site, you can forget that exists st. like validation.